# Ansible install JsReport on CentOS 7

Tags: npm, ansible, centos7, jsreport

I am having hard time writing ansible script for installing JsReport on CentOS 7.
I am trying to translate these operations:
https://jsreport.net/learn/centos

into ansible script.

What i tried so far is:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: install wget
    yum:
      name: wget
      state: latest      
  - name: download nvm
    get_url: url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh  dest=/opt/nvm-install.sh 
  - name: Changing perm of "/opt/nvm-install.sh", adding "+x"
    file: dest=/opt/nvm-install.sh mode=a+x
  - name: Execute the script
    command: sh /opt/nvm-install.sh
  - name: Changing perm of "~/.nvm/nvm.sh", adding "+x"
    file: dest=~/.nvm/nvm.sh mode=a+x   

  - name: Make nvm command work in current terminal, Install node and set version, npm install jsreport-cli 
    shell: |
      source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
      nvm install 8.11.3 
      npm install jsreport-cli -g
      mkdir jsreportapp
      jsreportapp
      jsreport init
      jsreport configure


  - name: download install-google-chrome.sh
    get_url: url=https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh  dest=/opt/install-google-chrome.sh
  - name: Changing perm of "/opt/install-google-chrome.sh", adding "+x"
    file: dest=/opt/install-google-chrome.sh mode=a+x   
  - name: Execute the script
    command: sh /opt/install-google-chrome.sh
```

Usually i start the ansible scripts with follow command:

```
sudo ansible-playbook install_jsreport.yml
```

I am not sure is that a good practice to use `sudo` here, or do i have to use `shell` here?

In the script above i get following error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh\n nvm install 8.11.3\n npm install jsreport-cli -g\n
>   mkdir jsreportapp\n jsreportapp\n jsreport init\n jsreport configure",
>   "delta": "0:01:03.627957", "end": "2019-04-19 15:22:26.374742", "msg":
>   "non-zero return code", "rc": -2, "start": "2019-04-19
>   15:21:22.746785", "stderr": "v8.11.3 is already installed.\nmkdir:
>   cannot create directory ‘jsreportapp’: File exists\n/bin/sh: line 4:
>   jsreportapp: command not found\nUnexpected error happened: Command
>   failed: npm i -S jsreport\nsh: node: command not found\nnpm WARN
>   pdfjs-dist@2.0.489 requires a peer of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.\nnpm
>   WARN worker-loader@1.1.1 requires a peer of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0
>   || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies
>   yourself.\nnpm WARN jsreport-server@ No description\nnpm WARN
>   jsreport-server@ No repository field.\nnpm WARN jsreport-server@ No
>   license field.\nnpm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   fsevents@1.2.8 (node_modules/fsevents):\nnpm WARN notsup SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.8: wanted
>   {\"os\":\"darwin\",\"arch\":\"any\"} (current:
>   {\"os\":\"linux\",\"arch\":\"x64\"})\n\nnpm ERR! file sh\nnpm ERR!
>   code ELIFECYCLE\nnpm ERR! errno ENOENT\nnpm ERR! syscall spawn\nnpm
>   ERR! puppeteer@1.12.2 install: `node install.js`\nnpm ERR! spawn
>   ENOENT\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@1.12.2 install
>   script.\nnpm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
>   likely additional logging output above.\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of
>   this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!
>   /root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-19T13_22_24_770Z-debug.log\n (1). \ncaused by
>   error (1) -> meta =
>   {\"killed\":false,\"code\":1,\"signal\":null,\"cmd\":\"npm i -S
>   jsreport\"}, stack = Error: \n    at ChildProcess.exithandler
>   (child_process.js:275:12)\n    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)\n    at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)\n    at maybeClose
>   (internal/child_process.js:925:16)\n    at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:209:5)", "stderr_lines": ["v8.11.3 is
>   already installed.", "mkdir: cannot create directory ‘jsreportapp’:
>   File exists", "/bin/sh: line 4: jsreportapp: command not found",
>   "Unexpected error happened: Command failed: npm i -S jsreport", "sh:
>   node: command not found", "npm WARN pdfjs-dist@2.0.489 requires a peer
>   of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install
>   peer dependencies yourself.", "npm WARN worker-loader@1.1.1 requires a
>   peer of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself.", "npm WARN jsreport-server@
>   No description", "npm WARN jsreport-server@ No repository field.",
>   "npm WARN jsreport-server@ No license field.", "npm WARN optional
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.8
>   (node_modules/fsevents):", "npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL
>   DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.8: wanted
>   {\"os\":\"darwin\",\"arch\":\"any\"} (current:
>   {\"os\":\"linux\",\"arch\":\"x64\"})", "", "npm ERR! file sh", "npm
>   ERR! code ELIFECYCLE", "npm ERR! errno ENOENT", "npm ERR! syscall
>   spawn", "npm ERR! puppeteer@1.12.2 install: `node install.js`", "npm
>   ERR! spawn ENOENT", "npm ERR! ", "npm ERR! Failed at the
>   puppeteer@1.12.2 install script.", "npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.",
>   "", "npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:", "npm ERR! 
>   /root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-19T13_22_24_770Z-debug.log", " (1). ",
>   "caused by error (1) -> meta =
>   {\"killed\":false,\"code\":1,\"signal\":null,\"cmd\":\"npm i -S
>   jsreport\"}, stack = Error: ", "    at ChildProcess.exithandler
>   (child_process.js:275:12)", "    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)", "
>   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)", "    at maybeClose
>   (internal/child_process.js:925:16)", "    at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:209:5)"], "stdout": "Now using node v8.11.3
>   (npm v5.6.0)\n/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/jsreport ->
>   /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/jsreport-cli/cli.js\n+
>   jsreport-cli@2.0.6\nadded 333 packages in 16.187s\njsreport
>   installation not found, installing jsreport latest version now, wait a
>   moment...\n? Do you want to enable web server? (Y/n)
>   \u001b[42D\u001b[42C", "stdout_lines": ["Now using node v8.11.3 (npm
>   v5.6.0)", "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/jsreport ->
>   /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/jsreport-cli/cli.js",
>   "+ jsreport-cli@2.0.6", "added 333 packages in 16.187s", "jsreport
>   installation not found, installing jsreport latest version now, wait a
>   moment...", "? Do you want to enable web server? (Y/n)
>   \u001b[42D\u001b[42C"]}

**EDIT (regarding larsks answer):**

> TASK [init jsreportapp directory]
>   ************************************************************************************************************* fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ".
>   ~/.nvm/nvm.sh\n jsreport init", "delta": "0:00:46.367234", "end":
>   "2019-04-23 10:12:46.142142", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1,
>   "start": "2019-04-23 10:11:59.774908", "stderr": "Unexpected error
>   happened: Command failed: npm i -S jsreport\nsh: node: command not
>   found\nnpm WARN pdfjs-dist@2.0.489 requires a peer of webpack@^2.0.0
>   || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies
>   yourself.\nnpm WARN worker-loader@1.1.1 requires a peer of
>   webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself.\nnpm WARN jsreport-server@ No
>   description\nnpm WARN jsreport-server@ No repository field.\nnpm WARN
>   jsreport-server@ No license field.\nnpm WARN optional SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.8 (node_modules/fsevents):\nnpm WARN
>   notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.2.8: wanted {\"os\":\"darwin\",\"arch\":\"any\"} (current:
>   {\"os\":\"linux\",\"arch\":\"x64\"})\n\nnpm ERR! file sh\nnpm ERR!
>   code ELIFECYCLE\nnpm ERR! errno ENOENT\nnpm ERR! syscall spawn\nnpm
>   ERR! puppeteer@1.12.2 install: `node install.js`\nnpm ERR! spawn
>   ENOENT\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@1.12.2 install
>   script.\nnpm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
>   likely additional logging output above.\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of
>   this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!
>   /root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-23T08_12_46_089Z-debug.log\n (1). \ncaused by
>   error (1) -> meta =
>   {\"killed\":false,\"code\":1,\"signal\":null,\"cmd\":\"npm i -S
>   jsreport\"}, stack = Error: \n    at ChildProcess.exithandler
>   (child_process.js:275:12)\n    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)\n    at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)\n    at maybeClose
>   (internal/child_process.js:925:16)\n    at Socket.stream.socket.on
>   (internal/child_process.js:346:11)\n    at emitOne
>   (events.js:116:13)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)\n    at
>   Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:557:12)", "stderr_lines":
>   ["Unexpected error happened: Command failed: npm i -S jsreport", "sh:
>   node: command not found", "npm WARN pdfjs-dist@2.0.489 requires a peer
>   of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install
>   peer dependencies yourself.", "npm WARN worker-loader@1.1.1 requires a
>   peer of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself.", "npm WARN jsreport-server@
>   No description", "npm WARN jsreport-server@ No repository field.",
>   "npm WARN jsreport-server@ No license field.", "npm WARN optional
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.8
>   (node_modules/fsevents):", "npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL
>   DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.8: wanted
>   {\"os\":\"darwin\",\"arch\":\"any\"} (current:
>   {\"os\":\"linux\",\"arch\":\"x64\"})", "", "npm ERR! file sh", "npm
>   ERR! code ELIFECYCLE", "npm ERR! errno ENOENT", "npm ERR! syscall
>   spawn", "npm ERR! puppeteer@1.12.2 install: `node install.js`", "npm
>   ERR! spawn ENOENT", "npm ERR! ", "npm ERR! Failed at the
>   puppeteer@1.12.2 install script.", "npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.",
>   "", "npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:", "npm ERR! 
>   /root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-23T08_12_46_089Z-debug.log", " (1). ",
>   "caused by error (1) -> meta =
>   {\"killed\":false,\"code\":1,\"signal\":null,\"cmd\":\"npm i -S
>   jsreport\"}, stack = Error: ", "    at ChildProcess.exithandler
>   (child_process.js:275:12)", "    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)", "
>   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)", "    at maybeClose
>   (internal/child_process.js:925:16)", "    at Socket.stream.socket.on
>   (internal/child_process.js:346:11)", "    at emitOne
>   (events.js:116:13)", "    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)", "    at
>   Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:557:12)"], "stdout":
>   "jsreport installation not found, installing jsreport latest version
>   now, wait a moment...", "stdout_lines": ["jsreport installation not
>   found, installing jsreport latest version now, wait a moment..."]}

**EDIT2:**

After  deleting the `temp` and making these commands on localhost:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R jsReport/
npm install puppeteer jsreport-chrome-pdf
```

And afterwards running your playbook with sudo it worked without error.

**Edit 3:**

Adding:

```
- name: install puppeteer 
  shell: |
    . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
    npm install puppeteer  -g
  args:
    creates: "~/.nvm/versions/node/v{{ node_version }}/lib/node_modules/puppeteer "
```

gives following error:

> TASK [install puppeteer]
>   ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ".
>   ~/.nvm/nvm.sh\n npm install puppeteer -g", "delta": "0:00:04.178220",
>   "end": "2019-04-23 11:39:44.413525", "msg": "non-zero return code",
>   "rc": 1, "start": "2019-04-23 11:39:40.235305", "stderr": "sh: node:
>   command not found\nnpm ERR! file sh\nnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE\nnpm
>   ERR! errno ENOENT\nnpm ERR! syscall spawn\nnpm ERR! puppeteer@1.14.0
>   install: `node install.js`\nnpm ERR! spawn ENOENT\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR!
>   Failed at the puppeteer@1.14.0 install script.\nnpm ERR! This is
>   probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found
>   in:\nnpm ERR!
>   /root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-23T09_39_44_391Z-debug.log", "stderr_lines":
>   ["sh: node: command not found", "npm ERR! file sh", "npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE", "npm ERR! errno ENOENT", "npm ERR! syscall spawn", "npm
>   ERR! puppeteer@1.14.0 install: `node install.js`", "npm ERR! spawn
>   ENOENT", "npm ERR! ", "npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@1.14.0 install
>   script.", "npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
>   likely additional logging output above.", "", "npm ERR! A complete log
>   of this run can be found in:", "npm ERR!
>   /root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-23T09_39_44_391Z-debug.log"], "stdout": "\n>
>   puppeteer@1.14.0 install
>   /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/puppeteer\n> node
>   install.js", "stdout_lines": ["", "> puppeteer@1.14.0 install
>   /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/puppeteer", "> node
>   install.js"]}

**EDIT4:**

I tried something like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    node_version: 8.11.3
    nvm_version: 0.33.11

  tasks:

    - name: Add the user 'jsreport'
      user:
        name: jsreport
        system: true  

    - name: install wget
      yum:
        name: wget
        state: latest
      become: true
      become_user: jsreport   

    - name: download nvm
      get_url:
        url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v{{ nvm_version }}/install.sh"
        dest: /opt/nvm-install.sh
      become: true
      become_user: jsreport    

    - name: Changing perm of "/opt/nvm-install.sh", adding "+x"
      file:
        dest: /opt/nvm-install.sh
        mode: "a+x"
      become: true
      become_user: jsreport  

    - name: Execute the script
      command: /opt/nvm-install.sh
      args:
        creates: ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
      become: true
      become_user: jsreport  

    - name: Changing perm of "~/.nvm/nvm.sh", adding "+x"
      file:
        dest: ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
        mode: "a+x"
      become: true
      become_user: jsreport  

    - name: install node
      shell: |
        . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
        nvm install {{ node_version }}
      args:
        creates: "~/.nvm/versions/node/v{{ node_version }}"
      become: true
      become_user: jsreport  

    - name: install jsreport-cli
      shell: |
        . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
        npm install jsreport-cli -g
      args:
        creates: "~/.nvm/versions/node/v{{ node_version }}/lib/node_modules/jsreport-cli"
      become: true
      become_user: jsreport  


    - name: install jsreport-chrome-pdf
      shell: |
        . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
        npm install jsreport-chrome-pdf -g
      args:
        creates: "~/.nvm/versions/node/v{{ node_version }}/lib/node_modules/jsreport-chrome-pdf"       
      become: true
      become_user: jsreport  


    - name: install puppeteer 
      shell: |
        . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
        npm install puppeteer  -g
      become: true
      become_user: jsreport  
      args:
        creates: "~.nvm/versions/node/v{{ node_version }}/lib/node_modules/puppeteer "    

    - name: create jsreportapp directory
      file:
        path: ./jsreportapp
        state: directory
      become: true
      become_user: jsreport  


    - name: init jsreportapp directory
      shell: |
        . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
        jsreport init
      args:
        chdir: ./jsreportapp
        creates: ./package-lock.json
      become: true
      become_user: jsreport
```

afterwards when i am on user `jsreport` 
I run `jsreport configure` command
Then i edited this config to set:

> "chrome": {   "launchOptions": {
>       "args": ["--no-sandbox"]   } }

Then i run `jsreport start` and get error saying:

> Couldn't find a jsreport installation necessary to check if the
>   command is available, if the command is a valid one try to install
>   jsreport first. (1). caused by error (1) -> stack = Error:
>       at Promise (/home/jsreport/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/jsreport-cli/lib/instanceHandler.js:55:21)
>       at new Promise ()
>       at Object.find (/home/jsreport/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/jsreport-cli/lib/instanceHandler.js:47:10)
>       at *getInstance* (/home/jsreport/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/jsreport-cli/lib/commander.js:768:10)
>       at exports.handler (/home/jsreport/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/jsreport-cli/lib/commands/start.js:56:5)
>       at Commander.executeCommand (/home/jsreport/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/jsreport-cli/lib/commander.js:389:28)
>       at Object.handler (/home/jsreport/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/jsreport-cli/lib/commander.js:559:16)
>       at Object.self.runCommand (/home/jsreport/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/jsreport-cli/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:170:22)
>       at parseArgs (/home/jsreport/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/jsreport-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:920:28)
>       at Object.Yargs.self.parse (/home/jsreport/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/jsreport-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:499:18)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that the `jsreport configure` command is interactive.  If you were to run it manually, you would see:

```
$ jsreport configure
? Do you want to enable web server? (Y/n)
```

But if you run that command without an attached terminal (which is how it is run by Ansible), it will fail with a non-zero exit code:

```
[root@365f191cdad1 ~]# jsreport configure < /dev/null 
? Do you want to enable web server? (Y/n) 
[root@365f191cdad1 ~]# echo $?
130
```

Since this is the last command in your shell script, it becomes the exit code of your shell script.  Since your shell script exits with a non-zero error, Ansible considers the task failed, and aborts the playbook.

If you were to remove the call to `jsreport configure`, you playbook would *almost* work, except there appears to be a typo in your script.  You have:

```
  mkdir jsreportapp
  jsreportapp
```

I think you're missing a `cd` there:

```
  mkdir jsreportapp
  cd jsreportapp
```

In other words, this runs without errors:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: install wget
    yum:
      name: wget
      state: latest      
  - name: download nvm
    get_url: url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh  dest=/opt/nvm-install.sh 
  - name: Changing perm of "/opt/nvm-install.sh", adding "+x"
    file: dest=/opt/nvm-install.sh mode=a+x
  - name: Execute the script
    command: sh /opt/nvm-install.sh
  - name: Changing perm of "~/.nvm/nvm.sh", adding "+x"
    file: dest=~/.nvm/nvm.sh mode=a+x   
  - name: Make nvm command work in current terminal, Install node and set version, npm install jsreport-cli 
    shell: |
      source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
      nvm install 8.11.3 
      npm install jsreport-cli -g
      mkdir jsreportapp
      cd jsreportapp
      jsreport init
```

But there are still a number of things here worth fixing.  First, you're getting an error from `mkdir jsreportapp`, which fails if the directory already exists.  You could call `mkdir -p` instead, but it's probably better to move this into a separate task, and then split up your final task as suggested by OmPrakashP:

```
- name: install node
  shell: |
    . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
    nvm install 8.11.3

- name: install jsreport-cli
  shell: |
    . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
    npm install jsreport-cli -g

- name: create jsreportapp directory
  file:
    path: ./jsreportapp
    state: directory

- name: init jsreportapp directory
  shell: |
    . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
    jsreport init
  args:
    chdir: ./jsreportapp
```

Rather than running `jsreport configure`, which is an interactive command, consider just copying in the appropriate `jsreport.config.json` using an Ansible `copy` task, or templating it using the `template` module if you want to be able to set things dynamically as part of the playbook run.

My final playbook -- including some minor stylistic changes (always use yaml syntax for module options, rather than key=value) and some idempotency changes (avoid re-running installation tasks, etc) -- looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    node_version: 8.11.3
    nvm_version: 0.33.11

  tasks:

    - name: install wget
      become: true
      yum:
        name: wget
        state: latest

    - name: download nvm
      get_url:
        url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v{{ nvm_version }}/install.sh
        dest: ~/nvm-install.sh

    - name: Changing perm of "/opt/nvm-install.sh", adding "+x"
      file:
        dest: ~/nvm-install.sh
        mode: "a+x"

    - name: Execute the script
      command: ~/nvm-install.sh
      args:
        creates: ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

    - name: Changing perm of "~/.nvm/nvm.sh", adding "+x"
      file:
        dest: ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
        mode: "a+x"

    - name: install node
      shell: |
        . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
        nvm install {{ node_version }}
      args:
        creates: "~/.nvm/versions/node/v{{ node_version }}"

    - name: install jsreport-cli
      shell: |
        . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
        npm install jsreport-cli -g
      args:
        creates: "~/.nvm/versions/node/v{{ node_version }}/lib/node_modules/jsreport-cli"

    - name: create jsreportapp directory
      file:
        path: ./jsreportapp
        state: directory

    - name: init jsreportapp directory
      shell: |
        . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
        jsreport init
      args:
        chdir: ./jsreportapp
        creates: ./package-lock.json
```

You can find the above playbook in [this repository](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-55762634).

**Update**

I've edited the playbook so that it runs successfully as a non-root user.  This involved (a) adding `become: true` to the `wget` install task and (b) installing `nvm-install.sh` into the current user home directory rather than `/opt`.

You can see this running successfully as a non-root user here:

- https://asciinema.org/a/2gT4nLD66kHpWaxQZvCj13ySq

And running successfully a second time:

- https://asciinema.org/a/2gT4nLD66kHpWaxQZvCj13ySq

As you can see, the errors you're reporting don't crop up, and likely have something to do with your environment. You may want to try starting on a fresh system.

Before running `jsreport start`, remember that you need to source in the `~/.nvm/nvm.sh` script. If you do that it seems to work successfully:

- https://asciinema.org/a/xgE8I605D0c93qlAxlu17hMqu

Comment: I've got an error on `init jsreportapp directory` task:

See updated question for more details.

Comment: Also when running without `sudo` ( ansible-playbook 1_installJsReport.yml) i get:
Permission denied: '/home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1556007862.44-176731055500964/setup.py'"}

Good practice is running the playbook with sudo or not??

Comment: After  deleting the `temp` and making these commands on localhost:

sudo chmod 777 -R jsReport/
npm install puppeteer jsreport-chrome-pdfls

And afterwards running your playbook with sudo it worked without error.

Comment: task `install wget` needs to be root, so i need to execute playbook with sudo - you are not using `become: true` or something like that

Comment: I've tested your playbook on new CentOS 7 and get the same error as i posted in the question

Comment: I am confused by the "it worked without error" part vs "I get the same error" part.  It's not possible that you're getting the same error -- in the event of a failure, the output of this playbook will never be the same as what you posted (because we've split up the final task).

Comment: I had an error on one machine after "EDIT (regarding larsks answer):" section in question.
Then if i made stuff after "EDIT2" section in the question i've got rid of that error.

Comment: Also - i made your script running on new user `jsreport` and with two additional steps.
NPM Installing `jsreport-chrome-pdf` and npm installing `puppeteer`. I think that `puppeteer` can't be installed as root. What do you think about it ? About installing `puppeteer` as root see `edit 3` section in the question.

Comment: Please see my attempt to fix that. See "edit 4" section in the question. thanks.

Comment: I've updated the playbook to run without `sudo`. I've also added screen recordings of two successful runs.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - could you check out "edit 4" section in the question? I am asking about `jsreport configure` and `jsreport start` there - that are after ansible script. Thank you

Comment: Did you remember to source `~/.nvm/nvm.sh` before running `jsreport start`? See the most recent update to this answer, which includes a successful run of `jsreport start`.

Comment: I made it on two servers out of three. On one of the servers 
I run ```ansible-playbook 2_installJsReport.yml   --ask-sudo-pass```
I get this error:
```TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "failed to transfer file to /home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1556028020.4-223141154111361/AnsiballZ_setup.py: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1556028020.4-223141154111361/AnsiballZ_setup.py'"}```

Comment: That looks like there may be a `root`-owned directory in `/home/username`.  Consider `chown -R username /home/username/.ansible`.

Answer (score 0):

You playbook is failing at below stage

```
    shell: |
      source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
      nvm install 8.11.3 
      npm install jsreport-cli -g
      mkdir jsreportapp
      jsreportapp
      jsreport init
      jsreport configure
```

You can break it further into multiple tasks.

Here is what you should try first
https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-nodejs

Also check out this guide for **node module installation** 
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/npm_module.html

Comment: I know where it is falling. I am looking for complex solution, not tips. You can tip in the comment.

Comment: I am not a node/npm/nvm guy btw. I saw your task was doing so many things in one go which is not the ansible way of doing things. It makes your ansible playbook hard to visualize what went wrong. The links i have mentioned contains tasks for installing node packages(here you need jsreport-cli i guess) which might help. Also 'sudo' is not required for ansible-playbook command, so you can just leave that.

Comment: While not a complete answer, this is a great start that would make your problem far easier to diagnose.